# .net clickonce where is my bin folder?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I deployed my winforms application using clickonce however I cannot see the bin folder which I really need because all of the log files are generated in that folder.

The only items I see in the deployed folder are:
Application Files

Setup

"my application name" (Application Manifest)

Answer (score 1):

The application files folder is where your compiled output will be stored ready for the users to install from, this is not where the users actually execute the files from. When the application is installed on a users PC by running the setup or .application file, it will be installed into a subfolder underneath `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0` on the user's machine and executed from there. Your log files will likely be in this app folder.

Comment: @G Davison thank you! I found it where you said it would be.